# Confusion on simple probability concept

Tags: probability, statistics

If:
\begin{align}
Y&=h(z,\theta)+\epsilon\\
\theta&\sim \text{Unknown Distribution}\\
\epsilon &\sim N(0,\sigma^2)
\end{align}
My book states:
$$
f_{y|(\theta,\sigma)}=f_{\epsilon|\theta,\sigma}(y-h(z,\theta)|\theta,\sigma )
$$
I don't follow why.

(This is in context of something like Bayesian Regression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, so $y|\theta,\sigma = h(z,\theta) + \epsilon \sim N(h(z,\theta),\sigma^2)$.

The equation says that the density $f_{y|\theta,\sigma}$ at the point $y^*$ is precisely the same as the density $f_{\epsilon|\theta,\sigma}$ at the point $y^* - h(z,\theta)$. This is true because $f_{y|\theta,\sigma}$ is just a shifted version of $f_{\epsilon|\theta,\sigma}$. Does that make sense?